# OnBackPressed() doesn't work properly in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, fragment, androidx, bottomnavigationview, onbackpressed

I use BottomNavigationView But when I click on the back button, the menu icons doesn't change (but the fragments change).
For example, I am on the home menu and I am moved to that menu by touching the settings menu, but when I click on the back button, I am moved to the home fragment, but the home icon is not selected and it is still the settings icon.

I have used the following libraries.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

And also in XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

And in menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />
<item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_cart" />
<item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bookmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_bookmark" />
<item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_profile" />
```

And in java:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;
        actionId = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_cart:
                fragment = new CartFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_bookmark:
                fragment = new BookmarkFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And loadFragment():

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I haven't been working with `BottomNavigation` long time but what I remember is the fact that if you just change a `Fragment` that doesn't mean that icons selection will change too. You have to un-select already selected icon and select the one that should be selected. That's the way I've been doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside method `loadFragment` you already call `transaction.addToBackStack(null)` it means when you press back top `Fragment` will be pop and your menu still keep at current select.

1. If you want `finish` when press back you should remove call `transaction.addToBackStack(null)`
2. If you want to keep this behavior and you have to update menu, put this code inside your activity

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
        } else if (fragment instanceof CartFragment) {
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_cart);
        } // others your fragments
    }
```

Comment: When I remove this code(transaction.addToBackStack(null)), the first click on the back button will exit the application.
I want to go back to the previous fragment.

Comment: When I use the onAttachFragment method, The application does not run.